# Remove leading zeros from number

Tags: bash

How to convert all numbers in Bash/shell?

```
VAR=00005
VAR=00010
VAR=00601
VAR=00550
```

to

```
echo $VAR #5
echo $VAR #10
echo $VAR #601
echo $VAR #550
```

Comment: at all, nothing at all I do not know how to do it :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

or like this:

```
kent$  echo "00005
00010
00601
00550"|awk '$0*=1'
5
10
601
550
```

for your updated question (with VAR)

first of all, you should have different variable names, not all same as VAR.

see the example below:

```
kent$  VAR=00601

kent$  VAR=$((VAR+0))

kent$  echo $VAR
601
```

EDIT

for the comment.(08, 09 didn't work):

08, 09 worked here, might be something with my shell to do. I have zsh. I tested followings under bash, they worked. hope helps:

under zsh:

```
kent$  v=08

kent$  v=$((v+0))

kent$  echo $v
8
```

under bash, below worked

```
kent@7PLaptop:/tmp$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
kent@7PLaptop:/tmp$ v=08
kent@7PLaptop:/tmp$ v=$(sed 's/^0*//'<<< $v)
kent@7PLaptop:/tmp$ echo $v
8
```

Comment: VAR=08 #problem, VAR=09 #problem, result 0

Comment: @Charlie see the EDIT in answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
$> cat text    
00005
00010
00601
00550

$> sed -r 's/0*([0-9]*)/\1/' text    
5
10
601
550
```

Using `printf`:

```
$> while read n; do printf "%0d\n" $((10#$n)); done < text
5
10
601
550
```

Note, when a numerical format expects a number, the internal printf-command will use the common Bash arithmetic rules regarding the base. In order to force decimal representation and as a side effect also remove any leading zeros for a Bash variable we should use `$((10#$n))`

Comment: just curious, where did 8, 385 and 360 come in your printf? Octal ^_^

Comment: I've added explanations to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason people are having issues with `08` and `09` is because numbers with trailing zeros are treated by the shell as octals.  You can do something like this:

```sh
VAR="08"
let "VAR=10#${VAR}"
echo $VAR
```

to remove the <strike>trailing</strike> leading zeros.

Comment: you meant,leading zeros, not trailing. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `extglob`, you do not need any external process:

```
shopt -s extglob                       # Enable extended globbing
for i in 00005 00010 00601 00550; do
    echo ${i##+(0)}
done
```

Comment: this also avoids octal interpretation by treating the number as merely a string

Answer (score 2):

`echo $((10#${VAR}))` can do what you want

Works at least for bash and mksh.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html):

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A leading ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.

The [docs for mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm#Ss.Arithmetic_expressions) are more concise regarding the leading zeros:

> Prefixing with "10#" forces interpretation as decimal, even with leading zeros.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `printf` to add or remove leading zeros:

```
$ printf "%05d\n" 5    
00005

$ printf "%d\n" 00005
5

$ printf "%010d\n" 00005
0000000005
```

Comment: In your example using: `printf "%d\n" 00010` results in `8` because it parses it as octadecimal.

Answer (score -2):

to: ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ

```
printf "%d\n" 0000
printf "%d\n" 0001
printf "%d\n" 0002
printf "%d\n" 0003
printf "%d\n" 0007
printf "%d\n" 0008
printf "%d\n" 0009
printf "%d\n" 0010
printf "%d\n" 0011
printf "%d\n" 0012
```

result

```
0
1
2
3
7
0 line 8: printf: 0008: invalid octal number
0 line 9: printf: 0009: invalid octal number
8 !error - correctly 10
9 !error - correctly 11
10 !error - correctly 12
```

Comment: `n=0015; n=$((10#$n)); printf "%d\n" $n` → `15`